# How to setup dependency injection in MVC4 and WebApi with disposal?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-4

With the release of MVC4 there is now the webapi and IDependencyResolver interface in the Http namespace which uses an IDependencyScope for each request. This dependencyScope also gets disposed after each request. This is easy to setup by just setting it up in the application start and using GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.

Is this also possible for "normal" MVC controllers? Is there a look-alike interface or do I just need to do the disposal myself in my controllers or services?

Answer (score 2):

The reason Web API contains this scoping mechanism is because the HTTP Request can not always be used as a scope, since Web API can run in a self-hosted environment, which means there is no `HttpContext.Current`.

'Normal' MVC controllers on the other hand, will always run in a web environment, and there will therefore always be a HttpContext available, which means that this mechanism can be used as a way to define a scope. This is what the 'Per Web Request' lifestyle does, that many IoC containers provide. In other words, your MVC application doesn't need that scope, since they can always use a 'per web request' lifestyle.